# Please explain why is this UnboundLocalError occurring?

Tags: python, django

This is my code -
urls.py

```
path('post/<int:pk>/edit/',views.Edit_View, name = 'edit_view'),
```

views.py

```
def Edit_View(request,pk):
    try:
        my_form = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        raise Http404('Page Doesnt Found')
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=my_form)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('detail_view',pk=pk)
    else:
        return render (request, 'edit_view.html',{'form':form})
```

template

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="OK">
```

This is working fine, but when writing `form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=my_form)` after `if request.method == 'POST':` like

```
def Edit_View(request,pk):
    try:
        my_form = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        raise Http404('Page Doesnt Found')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=my_form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('detail_view',pk=pk)
    else:
        return render (request, 'edit_view.html',{'form':form})
```

it gives

`UnboundLocalError at /post/2/edit/
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment` error, i want to know why such thing happening ! why earlier this didn't happen and later such error occurred and what is this UnboundLocalError?

Please be guiding me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hint: What happens if the method isn't POST?

Comment: You are trying to use `form` when `request.method` equals `"POST"`, but it was never assigned.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sir, then its GET probably

Comment: @pault yeah Sir, have fixed my question..

Comment: The difference between the working code and the non-working version is the placement of the `form = ...` line. As the other commenters have stated, you are using the variable `form` in the `else` statement without first defining it.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak another hint: what happens in your view when the form is invalid? Your view probably will throw an error because you are not returning an `HttpResponse` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `form` in the `else` has not been assigned any value:

`else:
        return render (request, 'edit_view.html',{'form':form})`

The variable `form` was only assigned in the `if`. Python has specific scoping rules, and if those rules are broken, Python throws an exception. Python won't execute your code because your variable is unassigned in the event that the `else` is executed.

This question is answered in detail here: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Comment: Well, it compiles, but dies when run.

Comment: Good point, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. I gave incorrect wording. This isn't a matter of compiling; it's a matter of Python throwing an exception based on its own scope rules. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In side else part write this:

```
else:
    form = ProfileForm()
    return render (request, 'edit_view.html',{'form......
```

Comment: Also, make sure the you return a response when you have a POST'ed but invalid form. Right now, you aren't handling that.